# How to move an image (animation)?

Tags: java, image, animation

I'm trying to move the boat on the x-axis (without the keyboard yet). How can I relate the movement/ animation to the `boat.png` and not to any other image?

```
public class Mama extends Applet implements Runnable {

    int width, height;
    int x = 200;
    int y = 200;
    int dx = 1;
    Image img1, img2, img3, img4;

    @Override
    public void init(){
        setSize(627, 373);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        img1 = getImage(getCodeBase(),"Background.png");
        img2 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "boat.png");
        img3 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "LeftPalm.png");
        img4 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "RightPalm.png");

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(img2, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(img3, 40, 100, this);
        g.drawImage(img4, 450, 130, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){

            x += dx;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread generates an error.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) In this millennium, why AWT (`Applet`) rather than Swing (`JApplet`)?  2) For convenience and the best user experience, why not `JFrame` and [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) instead of `JApplet` *or* `Applet`?

Comment: Gads I might have just copy/pasted the *entire* comment from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14433321/418556)!  I only copied the last two points, but the first applies as well.

Comment: I don't understand the difference it'd make if I switched to Swing & JFrame?

Comment: The difference to the immediate problem?  Nil.  That is why I added them and the comment re blocking the EDT - as comments rather than an answer.  As to an answer, see in a moment..

Comment: (on reconsidering..) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   For images, generate them (simple black, buffered images) in code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things that stand out...

### The "Problem"

As has already been stated, you need to supply variable arguments to the image drawing process.  `g.drawImage(img2, x, y, this);`, this will allow you define where the image should be painted.

While you've implemented `Runnable`, you've actually not started any threads to call it.  This means, nothing is actually changing the variables.

In you `start` method, you should be calling something like `new Thread(this).start()`.

### Recommendations

Although you've tagged the question as Swing, you're using AWT components.  This isn't recommended (in fact applets are generally discouraged as they are troublesome - IMHO).  The other problem, as you are bound to find out shortly, is they are not double buffered, this generally leads to flickering when performing animation, which isn't desirable.

As a side note, it is also discouraged to override the `paint` method of top level containers like `Applet`.  Top level containers tend to contain a number additional components, by overriding the `paint` method like this, you destroy this setup.  Also, top level containers don't tend to be double buffered either.

The example below uses a `JFrame`, but it wouldn't take much to convert it to use a `JApplet` (just drop the `AnimationPanel` on to it.  This is another reason why extending from top level containers is generally discouraged ;)

[image]

```
public class AnimatedBoat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimatedBoat();
    }

    public AnimatedBoat() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new AnimationPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage boat;
        private int xPos = 0;
        private int direction = 1;

        public AnimationPane() {
            try {
                boat = ImageIO.read(new File("boat.png"));
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        xPos += direction;
                        if (xPos + boat.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                            xPos = getWidth() - boat.getWidth();
                            direction *= -1;
                        } else if (xPos < 0) {
                            xPos = 0;
                            direction *= -1;
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }

                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return boat == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(boat.getWidth() * 4, boat.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int y = getHeight() - boat.getHeight();
            g.drawImage(boat, xPos, y, this);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `g.drawImage(img2, 200, 200, this);` with `g.drawImage(img2, x, y, this);`

Comment: I did and it still doesn't move!