# How do I draw an image to a frame every second?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

This is all I have so far. I have read the oracle documentation on drawing and creating images, But I still cant figure it out.

```
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("BeachRoad_double_size.png"));

    final JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    frame.add(pane);


    int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Graphics gg = image.getGraphics();
            System.out.println("sdfs");
            pane.paintComponents(gg);
            //g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };
    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](Painting in AWT and Swing) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: You could also take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432816/how-to-move-an-image-animation/14436331#14436331) which shows how to render an image and simple animation

Comment: Don't invoke the painting rethods directly. You should be invoking repaint() on the component. Post your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Ill take a look at both of those.

Answer (score 3):

1. Painting is the responsibility to of the Swing framework.  It decides what, when and how much should be painted.  You can make requests to the system to perform updates, but it will be up to the sub system to decide when it will be executed.
2. You should never have a need to call `paintComponent` directly, in fact, you should never have a need to call `paint` directly
3. Your example is actually painting the component to the image.

Instead.  Create a custom component, say from something like `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and perform all you custom painting there...

```
public class ImagePane extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage bg;

    public ImagePane(BufferedImage bg) {
        this.bg = bg;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return bg = null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (bg != null) {
            g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

For more details

Comment: It runs an error that I dont understand when I type this, "final ImagePane imagepane = new ImagePane(image);"